# TypeError: 'Alien' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm working on a space shooter and I've made the sprites and added some basic collision detection, but when I added in collision detection for whether or not an `alien` sprite collides with the `player` sprite, it gave me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 93, in <module>
    game.new()
  File "main.py", line 33, in new
    self.run()
  File "main.py", line 45, in run
    self.collision()
  File "main.py", line 58, in collision
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.alien, False)
  File "C:\Users\sidna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1525, in spritecollide
    return [s for s in group if spritecollide(s.rect)]
TypeError: 'Alien' object is not iterable
```

Here's my code:

main.py

```
# IMPORTS
import pygame, random
from sprites import *
from config import *

# GAME
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        # INIT PYGAME
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()

        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

    # NEW GAME
    def new(self):
        self.allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.allAliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.player = Player()

        for i in range(ALIEN_AMOUNT):
            self.alien = Alien()
            self.allSprites.add(self.alien)
            self.allAliens.add(self.alien)

        self.allSprites.add(self.player)

        self.run()

    # RUN GAME
    def run(self):
        self.playing = True

        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)

            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.collision()

    # DRAW
    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)

        self.allSprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.allAliens.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.update()

    # DETECT COLLISION
    def collision(self):
        # alien collision with player
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.alien, False)

        if hits:
            running = False

    # CHECK FOR EVENTS
    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False

                self.running = False

    # UPDATE GAME
    def update(self):
        self.allSprites.update()
        self.allAliens.update()

    # GAME OVER
    def gameOver(self):
        pass

    # START SCREEN
    def startScreen(self):
        pass

    # END SCREEN
    def endScreen(self):
        pass

game = Game()
game.startScreen()

while game.running:
    game.new()
    game.gameOver()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

sprites.py

```
import pygame, random
from config import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/img/player.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.velX = 0

    def animate(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velX

    def collision(self):
        # collision with walls
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def control(self):
        self.velX = 0

        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.velX = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.velX = 5

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.collision()
        self.control()

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/img/alien.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.velY = random.randrange(1, 4)
        self.velX = random.randrange(-4, 4)

    def animate(self):
        self.rect.y += self.velY
        self.rect.x += self.velX

    def collision(self):
        # collision with walls
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -20 or self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.velY = random.randrange(1, 4)
            self.velX = random.randrange(-4, 4)

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.collision()
```

config.py

```
# IMPORTS
import pygame

# ENTIRE GAME VARIABLES
TITLE = "Alien Invasion"
WIDTH = 360
HEIGHT = 570
FPS = 60

# ALIEN CONFIG
ALIEN_AMOUNT = 10

# COLORS
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.alien, False)
```

The spritecollide() function works like this (from the docs):

```
spritecollide(sprite, group, dokill, collided = None) -> Sprite_list
```

You put 'self.alien' as the second parameter, but spritecollide expects a group there.  If you just want to collide two different sprites, you want to use collide_rect:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, self.alien)
```

You'll get back True/False whether the two sprites are colliding.

See here for details on all the various collision methods:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html